# Macbook Pro 2010 Screen goes blank

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

Have got this crash report and havnt been able to find a fix for a while now. Hoping someone can read what the problem is. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I can't make heads or tails out of that report, but one possible fix would be to [reinstall the os](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). This is essentially the same as "repair", assuming you don't erase the disk before doing it.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more when it happens? Is this from startup or when using an external display?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest visiting a Apple Authorized Service Provider to troubleshoot this (what i suspect is a hardware issue)
https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Unfortunately MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) intermittent black screen or loss of video Quality Program has ended
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554